# Find the max value of a newly created column and the value associated with it

Tags: python, dataframe

How to find the max value of a newly created column and the value associated with it?

I tried the following but it is giving me entire details about the value(country) associated with 'Golden_Ratio' column and not just the value.

```
summer_country_gold = summer_df.loc[summer_df['Golden_Ratio'].idxmax()]
```

It should be China and of datatype str

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a DataFrame like this one:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Golden_Ratio": [1, 3, 2],
                   "Country": ["Spain", "China", "Peru"]})
```

Then you need to extract the row with the maximum, and also the proper column:

```
df.loc[df["Golden_Ratio"].idxmax(), "Country"]
```

You can also select several elements at once:

```
gr, c = df.loc[df["Golden_Ratio"].idxmax(), ["Golden_Ratio", "Country"]]
```

Comment: At first, I have to get the maximum value of 'Golden_Ratio' and then find the country name ('Country_Name) associated with that maximum value and store both the results in two different variables.

Comment: Isn't it exactly what my last line of code is doing, with the "Golden_Ratio" in ```gr``` and the country in ```c```?

Comment: Yes got it, but it is returning dtype as object and I want str

Comment: What do you mean? Here, ```type(c)``` is ```str```.

Comment: I do not get it. This is what would be returned by ```df.loc[df["Golden_Ratio"].idxmax()]```, hence your code. Did you really try my code?

Comment: It is showing the following as output 
0.42
Country_Name    China
Name: 23, dtype: object

The error is as follows:
You have not found and stored the correct country associated with the 'gr' in 'c'.

It should be China and of datatype str

Comment: What is your version of Pandas? (```pd.__version__```)

Comment: pd.__version__ is 0.23.4